# How to use the onkeyup event to a TextField?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to use onkeyup event of text field, so we can count that character when enter the text.

Comment: Sounds like you've got an idea as to how to solve the problem. Let us know when you encounter difficulties implementing it.

Comment: I've tried the following, but the onkeyup event doesn't seem to fire for the TextField object :- 




new Ext.form.TextField({
  emptyText:'insert name',
  listeners: {
    'onkeyup': function(obj) {
      alert('test fire');
    }
  }
}),

Comment: you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. In the doc [field key events](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-event-keyup), it is written that key events get fired only if enableKeyEvents is set to true.

```
           {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Address',
                width: '100%',                    
                enableKeyEvents : true,
                listeners: { 
                    keyup : function(obj) { 
                     alert('test fire ' + obj.getValue()); 
                     } 
                   }
            },
```

Comment: Thanks event working fine !
now  can we get text character  in function  'Obj'  which we are entering  in text filed, so that we can  count the length of character ?

Comment: Use the getValue() method of the textfield object :- obj.getValue(). Have a look at the modified code above

Answer (score 2):

```
enableKeyEvents: true
```

For key events to work, you need to explicitly specify it.

Working POC code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create({
        xtype: 'panel',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            height: 100,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'field label',
                value: '1',
                enableKeyEvents: true,
                listeners: {
                    keyup: function() {
                        console.log("key Up called");
                    },
                    change: function() {
                        console.log('changed');
                    }
                }
            }]
        }]
    })
});
```

Working Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cbd

Comment: Thanks event working fine ! now can we get text character in function 'Obj' which we are entering in text filed, so that we can count the length of character ?